# XAMPP OSX Lion get mail to work

Tags: php, email, xampp

Although this has been asked before, due to the fact that no satisfactory answer was provided, I thought I'd bring up that subject once again.

So: how can I get PHP's mail function to work on a Mac (I am using OS X Lion) using XAMPP?

Currently, I have the following php.ini configuration:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.server.xts
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
sendmail_from = user@server.xts

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

So… why does it still not work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this myself, and found the answer at:

http://mabblog.com/blog/2011/09/lion-smtp-postfix-relay-and-dreamhost/

I won't repeat the instructions, but the basic idea is that Lion's sendmail command is simply a wrapper for postfix. So in order to enable sendmail, you have to configure postfix to relay mail to an external mail server that you are authorized to use.

Comment: After the step in that post where they have you create `sasl_passwd`, you must change the owner to `root` using: `sudo chown root:wheel /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`